# Python log python interpreter output

Tags: python, logging

I tried to build a logger that also loggs the full output from the python interpreter, what you normally see on the console.

This is my suggestion, it did not work.

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
stdoutStreamHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
stderrStreamHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(logpath)
logger.addHandler(stdoutStreamHandler)
logger.addHandler(stderrStreamHandler)
```

Comment: How well did my answer work for you? I am interested in your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure what you mean by logging the full output from the Python Interpreter, do you mean the command-line interpreter or the background interpreter at run-time?

Either way this may help: [trace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html)

This will allow you to execute any code with the trace, and will also allow you to write it out to a file:

> ```
> import sys
> import trace
>
> # create a Trace object, telling it what to ignore, and whether to
> # do tracing or line-counting or both.
> tracer = trace.Trace(
>     ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix],
>     trace=0,
>     count=1)
>
> # run the new command using the given tracer
> tracer.run('main()')
>
> # make a report, placing output in the current directory
> r = tracer.results()
> r.write_results(show_missing=True, coverdir=".")
> ```

I have not yet used it myself, but it could be possible to execute

```
logger.debug(r)
```

Which would create a record in your log file of the debug log level, you could, of course, change that to info, warning, error or critical.